# Tracking Published Date as Custom Variable for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track traffic with Google Analtyics based upon the post publish date. For example, what new articles are doing well or poorly compared to similarly published posts.

I added this before my analytics code with no avail:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push('_setCustomVar',1,'Publish Date','<?php the_date('F j, Y', '', ''); ?>', 3);</script>
```

Comment: are you adding this in your footer manually or is it being added via a plugin or some other manner? Can you be more descriptive about what you expected the result to be and what the result was.

Comment: Adding to my header manually because I read that it needs to before the GA call.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to see which new articles are getting traffic and which old articles are still getting traffic. I have no way of knowing in GA when the articles were actually published.